# SQL to list missing items or items that are not valid

Tags: sql

I have a list of users and a list of roles.
I'd like to extract reports of roles that users should have but don't and roles that they do have but shouldn't.
For example

```
User,   Dept,  Role
Jane, Manager, Add
Jane, Manager, Modify
Fred, Clerk, Modify
Fred, Clerk, Inquire

Dept, Task
Manager, Add
Manager, Modify
Manager, Delete
Manager, Inquire

Clerk, Inquire
Clerk, Add
```

My query should indicate that Jane is missing delete and inquire and Fred should not have modify.
Currently I'm getting many duplicates as whenver I say something like manager's task <> role's task it's including records such as Add <> Modify.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: where are the 'rules' defined that say who should have what?

Comment: @Randy, the unnamed table with fields "Dept", "Task" presumably encodes the rules.  I believe those fields are something like "Named Permission Group" and "Specific Permission", respectively.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate inference from your question and data is that your tables are misdesigned, permitting ambiguity and error (missing or impoperly granted privileges) where there should be none.

However, working with what you have:

#### Missing Privileges ("Roles")

```
   SELECT d.User, d.Dept, d."Should Have" as "Missing"
     FROM (   SELECT DISTINCT udr.User, udr.Dept, dt.Task AS "Should Have"
                FROM UserDeptRole udr
           LEFT JOIN DeptTask dt
                     ON udr.Dept = dt.Dept) d
LEFT JOIN UserDeptRole udr2
          ON udr2.Dept = d.Dept AND udr2.Role = d."Should Have"
    WHERE udr2.Role is NULL;
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| User | Dept    | Missing |
+------+---------+---------+
| Jane | Manager | Inquire |
| Jane | Manager | Delete  |
| Fred | Clerk   | Add     |
+------+---------+---------+
```

#### Improperly Granted Privileges ("Roles")

```
   SELECT DISTINCT udr.User, udr.Role AS "Improper"
     FROM UserDeptRole udr
LEFT JOIN DeptTask dt
          ON udr.Dept = dt.Dept AND udr.Role = dt.Task
    WHERE dt.Task IS NULL
```

Output:

```
+------+----------+
| User | Improper |
+------+----------+
| Fred | Modify   |
+------+----------+
```

#### A Better Question

I encourage you to ask the SO community in a separate question how you can refactor your schema to avoid this very circumstance (missing or improper roles).

Comment: yes, don't just fix the records now, set it up so that you can't have bad records.

Comment: What does "poorly normalized" mean? (hints: "normalized" means 1NF, "fully normalized" means 5NF or 6NF).  Please state which normal form you think the tables are in and why.

Comment: @HLGEM: My thinking is to give the OP the benefit of the doubt and assume their second table models implied privileges and their first table models explicitly-assigned privileges and that there is a business requirement to model both.

Comment: @onedaywhen, I didn't mention normalization. However, since he wants to know who are the bad records, he is basically admitting to a bad design which needs fixing. To fix the data without fixing the design is a very bad idea as the problem will reoccur.

Comment: @HLGEM, I think that particular comment was intended for me.

Comment: @HLGEM: yes my comments as regards normalization are for pilcrow. "he is basically admitting to a bad design which needs fixing" -- I can only hope you aren't in the police force.

Comment: @HLGEM: ...in the data modelling trade, business rules as considered to have 'modality'. Alethic rules are those which cannot be violated e.g. a period's end date cannot precede its start date. Deontic rules are those that should not be violate but in practice may be violated e.g. being assigned a role that doesn't correspond to the tasks associated with one's department ;)

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL-99, tested on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
WITH ImpliedUserRoles
     AS
     (
      SELECT u."User", d.Dept, d.Task
        FROM UserRoles u
             INNER JOIN DeptTasks d
                ON u.Dept = d.Dept
     )
SELECT *, 'omission' AS role_error
  FROM ImpliedUserRoles
EXCEPT
SELECT *, 'omission' AS role_error
  FROM UserRoles
UNION
SELECT *, 'inclusion' AS role_error
  FROM UserRoles
EXCEPT
SELECT *, 'inclusion' AS role_error
  FROM ImpliedUserRoles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your user table, left outer join to your roles table on Dept -> Dept and Role -> Task. That way, if the user is not supposed to have that right, it will return null.

sample:

```
select u.User, case when d.Role is null then 0 else 1 end as Allowed
from User as U
left outer join Role as d
on U.Dept = d.Dept and U.Role = d.Task
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below will not be performant on large data sets!!

You can determine all the possibilities with a cross join and then, with the right join, only care about those that are missing.

(Below is T-SQL with table variables that represent the example data)

```
select allTasks.[User], allTasks.[Dept], allTasks.Task as MissingTask
from @users u
    right outer join (
        select u.[User], d.Dept, d.Task
        from @depts d
            cross join (select distinct [User], Dept as [Dept] from @users) u
        where d.Dept = u.Dept) allTasks on allTasks.[User] = u.[User] and allTasks.Dept = u.Dept and allTasks.Task = u.Role
where u.[User] is null
```

Results:

```
User       Dept       MissingTask
---------- ---------- -----------
Fred       Clerk      Add
Jane       Manager    Delete
Jane       Manager    Inquire

(3 row(s) affected)
```

This query will then find the rows that have a task they likely shouldn't:

```
select u.[User], u.Dept, u.Role as ExtraRole
from @users u
    left outer join @depts d on d.Task = u.Role and d.Dept = u.Dept
where d.Dept is null
```

Results:

```
User       Dept       ExtraRole
---------- ---------- ----------
Fred       Clerk      Modify

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input.